# Is there a way to sense the characteristic impedance of a transmission line?

Tags: impedance, transmission

Is there a way to sense the characteristic impedance of a transmission line?

If a transmission line between a driver and a receiver is 50ohm, is it possible to design a circuit at the receiver end to sense the characteristic impedance of the transmission line without knowing the impedance beforehand?

[image]

Comment: You need to know the reflection coefficient. Without knowing anything about the source (driver) and signal properties at source side (i.e. the amplitude, frequency content, etc.) you can't calculate the reflection coefficient. So no, you can't calculate or measure the line impedance with using measurements from receiver side only.

Comment: You can sense it from the driver end.  That's the way a TDR works.

Comment: I think if you can configure the Driver to send out a pulse train, and you know the output impedance of the driver, then there is a way. Either tune a termination resistance until the signal becomes rectangular, or measure the mismatch with a known termination resistor of e.g. 100 Ohm. Both way require you to somehow measure the line voltage as analog signal. Maybe there is a way to properly "convert" this measurement into a time domain measurement via some clever use of RC and a comparator.

Comment: You could attach a TDR at the receiver end and use that to measure the line impedance. Just be sure not to use a large enough TDR stimulus to damage your transmitter and/or receiver.